# How to set up an API Call for YouTube Data API? error code: 403, "Forbidden"

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to change the thumbnails and title of a video on my YouTube channel using this API Call which I make from a web-app on Bubble.io [Printscreen of API Call for Make changes to user's videos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGolk.png)

In Playground YouTube everything goes fine, the request works, the name of the video on the main YouTube channel changes, but the exact same json in bubble.io

```json
{
  "id": "-d4cbswHuSE",
  "snippet": {
    "title": "TESY api.",
    "thumbnails": {
      "default": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HCkvoed2iII/default.jpg"
      }
    },
    "categoryId": "22"
  }
}
```

gives this error:
"forbidden (403) forbidden Access forbidden . The request may may not be properly authorized"

Can you tell me what the problem could be? Maybe someone has already experienced something like this? [Prinscreen of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEYe1.jpg)